# Rspec, Rails 5, Ransack: test view index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ransack, rspec3

I have errors
ActionView::Template::Error:No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!
and I try test unit with source

```
it "displays all the users" do
assign(:users, [
  FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "slicer"),
  FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "dicer")
])

render

expect(rendered).to match /slicer/
expect(rendered).to match /dicer/
```

end

I uses ransack in method index of controllers

```
def index
@q = User.ransack params[:q]
@users = @q.result.newest._page params[:page]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xls{send_data @users.to_xsl}
end
```

end
and this my views

```
<div class="input-group search_inline">
  <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :user %>
    <%= f.search_field :user_cont, placeholder: t(".search") %>
    <%= f.submit t(".search"), name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary 
      btn_search" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
it "displays all the users" do

@q = User.ransack   // Index is expecting that

assign(:users, [
  FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "slicer"),
  FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "dicer")
])

render

expect(rendered).to match /slicer/
expect(rendered).to match /dicer/
```